# pickle unserializable python objects

Tags: python, pickle

I have an object from a class of particular python module that quantifies some chemical compounds. I am trying to pickle the output from one its functions, but I always get the error "TypeError: Cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object. I also tried dill, but it gives me the same error.

Is there any way I can get this to work?

Comment: Please add some code references to better understand the query.

Comment: Not every object is serializable.  If the question included a minimal example reproducing the issue in your context (i.e. using the classes you're using), it would be much easier for us to suggest a way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pickle a `BufferedReader` since by itself, it doesn't represent any real amount of data - just where it can read the data from.

If you can, I would suggest reading all data and serializing that instead. Note that if this `BufferedReader` represents a unending stream or large file, that doing this may not be possible and you might need to find a way to solve you problem without serialization (perhaps instead saving an item that instructs other code to make the same method call?)

Comment: Yes, it is reading from a very large file (which is something like an xml file). And this particular output allows  random access to the contents of the file by some tags. I currently have these outputs as a list , onto which I want to call another function that accesses each file, but I will probably have to change that now.

Comment: @rkm19 You can still try reading all the content from the buffered reader amd see where that gets you.

Comment: I can read all the contents, in a list comprehension, but it takes a very long time. I cant use multiprocessing for this too because of the same error. So maybe I will have to restructure my fucntions.

Comment: Then you probably can't pickle it in any fast way either. I would suggest asking a new question about that you're trying to solve with pickling